# display K and M in Angular nvd3 chart Yaxis

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

Would you please help me to change the display in my angular nvd3 yAxis2.
In fact I'm trying to change the display from for example from 9000 to 9K.
I know that may be it can be done using `d3.formatPrefix(".1", 1e6)` but I wasn't able to make it.
here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0ZKShm?p=preview) for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to use d3.formatPrefix(".1", 1e6).
you are already using the correctd format `d3.format(',.2f')(d)` just you need to change the `f` with `s` as mentioned in the d3 github site

```
The available type values are:

e - exponent notation.
f - fixed point notation.
g - either decimal or exponent notation, rounded to significant digits.
r - decimal notation, rounded to significant digits.
s - decimal notation with an SI prefix, rounded to significant digits.
% - multiply by 100, and then decimal notation with a percent sign.
p - multiply by 100, round to significant digits, and then decimal notation with a percent sign.
b - binary notation, rounded to integer.
o - octal notation, rounded to integer.
d - decimal notation, rounded to integer.
x - hexadecimal notation, using lower-case letters, rounded to integer.
X - hexadecimal notation, using upper-case letters, rounded to integer.
c - converts the integer to the corresponding unicode character before printing.

(none) - like g, but trim insignificant trailing zeros.
```